the cursor position doesn't change with the font size
I'm using stylish in chrome to format the web view, and I found something interesting, which cursor position doesn't change with the font-size.
example website: https://jqplay.org/s/61S_UA_ZEVM3Ykh

font-size: 14px


font-size: 20px


full actions:

gif
video



can anyone help me to adjust the cursor position same as font-size ?
thanks.

The textarea is managed by monaco-editor, a Javascript plugin. There is a div .selected-text which as far as I understand fakes the selection behavior. This div has a fixed width (388px here), fixed by Javascript on the DOM content loaded by the size of text. Changing the size in inspector won't trigger any JS code to resize this div. It's normal.

thanks @vincent-decaux, you have been a great inspiration to me. I've reproduced the issue in monaco-editor/example. So, any suggestion to appropriate to enlarge the font-size, and keep cursor update when modify the font-family ? BTW, I've using this stylish css to try modify the .monaco-editor
